# Appropriate reply to "Thank you for your time"

Tags: word-usage, phrases, expressions

How would native speakers reply to someone who says "Thank you for your time!" when ending a conversation.

I could think of the following phrases but I'm not quite sure:

1. "Yours too!"
2. "You too"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: .... But it depends on the dynamics of the conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
What if  I'd also like to thank the person for his/her time?

Comment: You can thank the person back if you like ... e.g. "*Likewise*". But this might not suit the register of younger / more informal interactions.

Comment: "Ain't no thang."

Comment: Ok! So does that imply "Likewise, thank you for your time"?

Comment: I think "my pleasure" is a polite answer when sb says "thanks for your time"